# find files with non-zero size in shell

Tags: bash, perl

I need to get a list of names of files with non-zero size inside a directory. This should be in a shell script, so bash (or a Perl one-liner) would be ideal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -size +0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /searchdir -type f -size +0c
```

will find files with a size of one or more bytes in `/searchdir` and below.

Comment: That will find directories as well as files.

Answer (score 1):

Shell only, avoiding find, without recursion into subdirectories:

bash (for unset GLOBIGNORE):

```
for file in .* *; do
  test . = "$file" && continue
  test .. = "$file" && continue
  # if you just want real files, no symlinks
  # test -L "$file" && continue
  test -f "$file" || continue
  test -s "$file" || continue
  # here do what you want with what is left
done
```